# Unable to get SMART metrics from Seagate Disks on Debian OS

Tags: linux, raid, hard-drive, smart

Referring to the question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/151288/making-sense-of-s-m-a-r-t), I too am trying to get all attributes out, as explained in this blog [here](https://www.backblaze.com/blog/hard-drive-smart-stats/).

I am using Debian 6 as OS, and installed smartmontools version 6.3 using apt-get. My 6 disks are on RAID. I first enabled the stats using the command

```
sudo smartctl -s on -o on -S on -d megaraid,0 /dev/sda
sudo smartctl -s on -o on -S on -d megaraid,1 /dev/sda
sudo smartctl -s on -o on -S on -d megaraid,2 /dev/sda
sudo smartctl -s on -o on -S on -d megaraid,3 /dev/sda
sudo smartctl -s on -o on -S on -d megaraid,4 /dev/sda
sudo smartctl -s on -o on -S on -d megaraid,5 /dev/sda
```

Once done, I am using the following command to get all the attributes out:

```
smartctl -a -i -d megaraid,0 /dev/sda
```

but I do not see any attributes as has been told in the blog article.

```
bash-4.1#     smartctl -a -i -d megaraid,0 /dev/sda
smartctl 6.3 2014-07-26 r3976 [x86_64-linux-2.6.32-5-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               SEAGATE
Product:              ST900MM0006
Revision:             LS08
Compliance:           SPC-4
User Capacity:        900,185,481,216 bytes [900 GB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
LB provisioning type: unreported, LBPME=-1, LBPRZ=0
Rotation Rate:        10000 rpm
Form Factor:          2.5 inches
Logical Unit id:      0x5000c500767033b3
Serial number:        S0N1MEKG
Device type:          disk
Transport protocol:   SAS (SPL-3)
Local Time is:        Wed Mar  4 13:17:30 2015 IST
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Enabled
Temperature Warning:  Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK

Current Drive Temperature:     21 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        50 C

Manufactured in week 22 of year 2014
Specified cycle count over device lifetime:  10000
Accumulated start-stop cycles:  118
Specified load-unload count over device lifetime:  300000
Accumulated load-unload cycles:  314
Elements in grown defect list: 0

Vendor (Seagate) cache information
  Blocks sent to initiator = 965779306
  Blocks received from initiator = 2971611077
  Blocks read from cache and sent to initiator = 403576599
  Number of read and write commands whose size <= segment size = 11852771
  Number of read and write commands whose size     segment size = 121

Vendor (Seagate/Hitachi) factory information
  number of hours powered up = 4833.13
  number of minutes until next internal SMART test = 54

Error counter log:
           Errors Corrected by           Total   Correction     Gigabytes    Total
               ECC          rereads/    errors   algorithm      processed    uncorrected
           fast | delayed   rewrites  corrected  invocations   [10^9 bytes]  errors
read:   3785944895        0         0  3785944895          0       2403.727           0
write:         0        0         0         0          0       4069.649           0
verify: 3308284580        0         0  3308284580          0      15953.521           0

Non-medium error count:        0

SMART Self-test log
Num  Test              Status                 segment  LifeTime  LBA_first_err [SK ASC ASQ]
     Description                              number   (hours)
# 1  Background short  Completed                  48       8                 - [-   -    -]
# 2  Reserved(7)       Completed                  32       8                 - [-   -    -]
# 3  Background short  Completed                  48       7                 - [-   -    -]

Long (extended) Self Test duration: 5616 seconds [93.6 minutes]
```

Any clue what am I missing here? How do I get the SMART metrics out?

Comment: Is SMART enabled in BIOS?

Comment: Yes, SMART is enabled.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to rely on the Hardware RAID utility instead?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot extract SMART information from a RAID array.
The array does have SMART information, the drives that make it do.

Dev sda is a RAID, not a unit (sd0, sd1 / sda1, sdb1 etc).
So extract your information from disk units, not array.

Comment: I get same results when I use /dev/sda1.

Comment: It all depends on the read method. Some applications can correctly read RAIDed drive units, some cannot. You need to find some app able to read the information correctly.